# generating all possible permutaions of given characters (A, B, C) for length given by user to make a String in C

Tags: c, permutation

I have to Generate a string using given character A B C for length given by user. Suppose If user gives 4 as length then code should display like:

```
AAAA  
AAAB  
AAAC  
AABA    
.  
.  
.  
CCCC.
```

I can generate a permutation of String ABC. but my question is if user give input 4 or 5 or 6
than How I can generate permutation of 4 or 5 or 6 character which only contain either A, B, C.please help.
could you please provide me code or steps how to code for.

Any tips, ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? And did you copied this verbatim from your homework? Because I am not understanding it (if you DID copy it verbatim, sorry to say but whoever wrote the question is a bad writer)

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't forget to check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you show some effort and post some code that you have tried and clearly stating you problem, people will be glad to help you!

Comment: This was answered yesterday.

Comment: Vote duplicate then please? (I don't have sufficient rep yet)

Comment: Sorry.... For Bad writing. MY question is : I have to make a string using  3 characters (like A, B, C) for a given length by user.void main(){
int number;
printf("Could you please press any number  \n");
scanf("%d", &number);
printf("Enterd number is=%d \n", number);
combination( number);could you please provide me code or steps how to code for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something recursive of this type ... this works for strings which have one occurrence of any character... so a little bit would do that you don't have to swap those elements which are same .. suppose you don't have to swap 'A' with 'A' or 'B' with 'B'.

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n) 
{
    int j; 
    if (i == n)
    printf("%s\n", a);
    else
    {
         for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
         {
             swap((a+i), (a+j));
             permute(a, i+1, n);
             swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Represent the permutations as numbers in a numeric system base 4. Map A to 0, B to 1 C to 2 and D to 3. Iterate over all numbers from 1 to 4<sup>4</sup>(256), represent each number in base 4 and replace digits with letters.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known recursion problem.

```
void f (char *dst, const char *src, int depth, int current) {
  int i;

  if (current >= depth) {
    dst[depth] = '\0';
    puts(dst);
  } else {
    for (i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      dst[current] = src[i];
      f (dst, src, depth, current + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for soln but there is little modification in your code.        Instead of if (current > depth) it should be if (current >= depth).